# Using window.opener causes CORS error

Tags: javascript, html, cors

I have an application that creates a pop-up window, which loads a page which then fetches data from the opening window, like so:

```
var globals = window.opener.globalsCache;
```

However, when deployed to production, this intermittently causes the following error:

```
DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame
```

Note that the popup window has exactly the same URL as the opener, except for the hash. *(i.e. https:/hostname.tld/application/#page-name )*.

Has anyone seen this issue before?  Any ideas on why it is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: This question might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame

Answer (score 2):

window.open uses another domain "window.opener" and so document.referrer won't match.  Check this ref. of same issue: [Guarantee the origin (parent URL) of a cross domain window.opener call by preliminary CORS call to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827302/guarantee-the-origin-parent-url-of-a-cross-domain-window-opener-call-by-prelim?rq=1)